# What is the point of the any type?

Tags: typescript

If I have a stand alone function, is there any difference between

```
function( var: Any){

}
```

And

```
function(var){

}
```

In the bottom example, will Typescript treat the function argument type as any since I didn't specify a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context.  If I have the following code...

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.map(function (x) { return x.toLowerCase(); });
```

Then the type of `x` is not `any` but `number` and this code will fail to compile because `toLowerCase` does not exist on type `number`.  The compiler is able to infer the type of `x` based on context.

If I write...

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.map(function (x: any) { return x.toLowerCase(); });
```

Then it will compile.  It will still fail at runtime of course.

In general, you should avoid using `any` and should prefer `unknown` in TS.

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice solely for the last line of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both function (with and without `any` as a type for the parameter) are the same. When you do not write `any` as a type yourself, and TypeScript cannot infer the type by itself, the parameter will have *implicit any* as type.

The *explicit any* can be used if you use the `--noImplicitAny` ([see docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)) flag with the TypeScript compiler. This will raise errors when you will try to compile your second function (without type).

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript by default treads all values which have no type definition as `any`. Thanks that,and because of that you can perform every action with these values.

What is the difference, the difference is if you prefer to have it implicit or explicit. Because of the type inference, sometimes you don't need to have explicit type declaration, but the value will have specific type. In other words not all arguments without type definition right after them are type `any`. Let me show it:

```
type F = (a: number) => number
// some other place
const f:F = a => a + 1;
```

As you can see, there is no explicit information close to argument `a` but still it is specific `number` type.

The thing comes to explicit information, using `any` gives developer clear vision about the type. There is even a rule in `tsconfig` about forcing using explicit `any` - **noImplicitAny**. And it is very good to set it true. Less confusion and questions, also it is easy to spot all places where the type is not specified. As you can just search by `:any` or ask your IDE to show all references.

In the final words, using explicit `any` is better for your project, as it removes confusion and marks all places which should have more specified type.